# creating a custom listview, but values contain "@" and what seems like a C pointer

Tags: java, android, custom-adapter

```
![](https://scontent-dub4-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/43125544_1705062639616259_4425322847673516032_n.jpg?_nc_cat=102&oh=641ab52118c35e228d9aba28076dbca8&oe=5C16DD7E)
```

this is my custom adapter class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Receipt> {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Receipt> receiptList;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Receipt> list) {
    super(context, 0 , list);
    mContext = context;
    receiptList = list;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItem = convertView;
    if(listItem == null)
        listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view,parent,false);

    Receipt receipt = receiptList.get(position);



    TextView name =listItem.findViewById(R.id.textView_name);
    name.setText(receipt.getShopName());

    TextView release =listItem.findViewById(R.id.textView_total);
    release.setText(receipt.getShopTotal());

    return listItem;
}
}
```

my receipt class

```
public class Receipt {

private String mShopName;
private String mShopTotal;


public Receipt(String mShopName, String mShopTotal) {
    this.mShopName = mShopName;
    this.mShopTotal = mShopTotal;
}

public String getShopName() {
    return mShopName;
}

public String getShopTotal() {
    return mShopTotal;
}
}
```

and here is my populateListView method

```
private ArrayList populateListView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in the ListView.");
        //get the data and append to a list
        Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
        ArrayList<Receipt> receiptList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
             mFilteringDatabase.takeInRow(data.getString(1));

            String displayedScreen = mFilteringDatabase.shopName();
            String displayedTotal= (mFilteringDatabase.total());
            receiptList.add(new Receipt(displayedScreen,displayedTotal));
        }
        mAdapter= new CustomAdapter(getContext(),receiptList);
        return receiptList;
    }
```

there seems to be some issue with the receipt class, as if i override the toString with a "return "test" " line, the error disappears, but only displays "test" of course

thanks in advance guys

edit, just to answer some of your questions, the reason i dont believe it is the scanner, is because when i just use string as the ArrayList type, and pass in only 1 value, the data comes in fine from the database, ie

[image], this is the code that fixes the issue but only for 1 of the 2 values (i.e. i can concat them and put them on the same line, but i want one right aligned and one left aligned so it wont work as a normal list view

```
private ArrayList populateListView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in the ListView.");
        //get the data and append to a list
        Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
        ArrayList<String> receiptList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
             mFilteringDatabase.takeInRow(data.getString(1));

            String displayedScreen = mFilteringDatabase.shopName();
            receiptList.add(displayedScreen);
        }

        return receiptList;
    }
```

Comment: How are you populating the database?

Comment: im using another class for that, im typing in data, and its stored as a receipt, im 100% sure that this works since i had it working in my previous build but i reset that branch and im left wondering how on earth i fixed it in the first place haha

Comment: How do you store it as receipt? You can't store custom data type in database.. The listview that is getting displayed for you is the object hashcodes. So i am guessing you are storing the object hashcodes (by default, Receipt.toString() returns this) instead.

Comment: the issue is on reading your data cursor... could you please post your class mFilteringDatabase? could you add a log for data.getString(1) to see if your data is  retrived correctly?  you have to change cursor to do/while loop, and call   cursor.moveToFirst().

Comment: That looks like the result of a non-overridden toString() method in an object. Somewhere in your code you are calling it and it returns the object class along with the memory address it's stored at.

Comment: i edited my post above to show you guys that its definitely not an issue with the database, as the data displays fine when it is a string

Comment: On this line String displayedTotal= (mFilteringDatabase.total()); displayedTotal is the value you expected? if not may be you should check that total() method to override the to String or that it returns proper value

Comment: yup, just checked, both values on their own are coming back as the correct data, they are only incorrect when using a custom listview